# Self-implemented C++ exception class

Tags: c++, exception

I wrote my own exception class, deriving from `std::runtime_error` to have Error-IDs, timestamps and inner exceptions. It seems to work, but are there any drawbacks?

The only thing I see is the deep-copy in the copy-constructor, which is not efficient, when there are many nested exceptions. But exceptions should be rare and not be nested too much, so I think it's a downside I can cope with.

```
#pragma once

#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <memory>


class MyException : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    MyException(const MyException& exception)
        : std::runtime_error(exception.what()),
        exceptionId(exception.id()),
        ts(exception.timestamp()),
        innerException(NULL)
    {
        if (exception.inner() != NULL)
        {
            innerException = new MyException(*exception.inner());
        }
        else
        {
            innerException = NULL;
        }
    }

    MyException(const std::string& _Message)
        : std::runtime_error(_Message),
            exceptionId(0),
        innerException(NULL)
    {
        time(&ts);
    }

    MyException(const std::string& _Message, unsigned int id)
        : std::runtime_error(_Message),
        exceptionId(id),
        innerException(NULL)
    {
        time(&ts);
    }

    MyException(const std::string& _Message, unsigned int id, MyException* innerException)
        : std::runtime_error(_Message),
        exceptionId(id),
        innerException(new MyException(*innerException))
    {
        time(&ts);
    }

    virtual ~MyException()
    {
        delete innerException;
    }

    unsigned int id() const { return exceptionId; }
    time_t timestamp() const { return ts; }
    const MyException* inner() const { return innerException; }

private:
    unsigned int exceptionId;
    time_t ts;
    const MyException* innerException;
};
```

This is how I would use it:

```
void handleException(MyException *ex)
{
    cout << "exception " << ex->id() << " - " << ex->what() << endl;
    const MyException* innerException = ex->inner();
    int t = 1;
    while (innerException != NULL)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<t; ++i)
        {
            cout << "\t";
        }
        ++t;
        cout << "inner exception " << innerException->id() << " - " << innerException->what() << endl;
        innerException = innerException->inner();
    }
}

void throwRecursive(int temp)
{
    if (temp == 0)
    {
        throw runtime_error("std::runtime_error");
    }

    try
    {
        throwRecursive(--temp);
    }
    catch (MyException &ex)
    {
        throw MyException("MyException", (temp+1), &ex);
    }
    catch (exception &ex)
    {
        throw MyException(ex.what(), (temp+1));
    }
}

void myExceptionTest()
{
    try
    {
        throwRecursive(3);
    }
    catch (MyException &ex)
    {
        handleException(&ex);
    }
}
```

And the output:

> ```
> exception 3 - MyException
>         inner exception 2 - MyException
>                 inner exception 1 - std::runtime_error
> ```

I already found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801194/is-there-anything-wrong-with-my-self-implemented-exception-class#comment17310405_12801194) that I'm violating the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29), having forgotten the copy assignment operator.

Other issues mentioned: cloning, reserved names and throw specifications.

Can anyone tell me more about that?

Comment: First glance: `innerException == NULL;` could be quite a nasty typo.

Answer (score 8):

Not all compilers support `#pragma once`

```
#pragma once
```

There are C++ equivalent of most C libraries that put the appropriate interface into the standard namespace.

```
#include <time.h>

// Prefer

#include <ctime>
```

My pet peeve (OK second after `using namespace std;`); because everybody thinks they know the rules but get it wrong all the time:

```
_Message
```

**DO NOT USE IDENTIFIERS WITH A LEADING UNDERSCORE**. Even if you know the rules most people get it wrong (such as this case) as a result it leads to maintenance problems. https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065 An identifier with a leading underscore and a capital letter is *reserved* in all scopes (i.e. the implementation is potentially going to use a macro with that name and Message seems like a prime candidate).

Your three versions of the constructor can be written as a single constructor:

```
    MyException( const std::string& _Message
               , unsigned            int id = 0             // Use default values
               , MyException*        innerException = NULL) // That way you do not have
        : std::runtime_error(_Message)                      // three versions of the
        , exceptionId(id)                                   // same constructor
        , innerException(innerException)
    {
        time(&ts);
    }
```

A class is its own friend.
So you don't need to call getter methods to access members of the object you are copying in the copy constructor; you can just get the values. When constructing the base class (std::runtime_error) why not take advantage of its copy constructor (it may have optimizations that you are failing to take use of by using the non standard version).

```
MyException(const MyException& exception)
    : std::runtime_error(exception)
    , exceptionId(exception.exceptionId)
    , ts(exception.ts)
    , innerException(NULL)
```

The inner exception is passed around as a pointer. So we have no ownership semantics associated with it. You attempt to take ownership but fail (because you do not implement the rule of 3 (5 in C++11)).

```
{
    if (exception.inner != NULL)
    {
        // Slicing problem if exception.inner is derived from MyException
        innerException = new MyException(exception.inner);
    }
    else
    {
        // Already set in the initializer list no need to set again.
        innerException = NULL;
    }
}
```

Also because of the way you implement it you can not subclass `MyException` because the copy constructor will slice your object on copy. You should probably use a smart pointer to handle ownership of the exception. Since sharing the same exception would solve most of your problems the easy way out is to use `shared_ptr<X>`. Personally I would make `X` a std::runtime_error`not`MyException` thus allowing you to chain on standard exceptions (or anything derived from them).

In the handler:

```
void handleException(MyException *ex)
```

Why pass a pointer to the exception. Now you have to check for NULL. Pass it as a reference.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this detailed answer. I'm new to this site. Can I simply edit my question by replacing my code by an improved version for a next revision step?

Comment: @Ben: Rather than replace your answer Add a new section below with a title called `###edit 1`

Comment: I edited my question. Please have a look at it!